# How to calculating Zero Crossing Rate (ZCR) & Mean Crossing Rate (MCR) in an array?

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, array-formulas

I am trying to create two python methods that provides ZCR & MCR of an array
 as mentioned in the [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323935725_Analyzing_User_Emotions_via_Physiology_Signals)

[image]

Here are my code for ZCR :

```py
    def getZeroCrossingRate(self,arr):
        my_array = np.array(arr)
        return float("{0:.2f}".format((((my_array[:-1] * my_array[1:]) < 0).sum())/len(arr)))
```

```
Input  : [1,2,-3,4,5,-6,-2,-6,2]
Output : 0.44
```

For **MCR** , should i average out the ZCR calculated from other segments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your ZCR function to compute the MCR like so:

```py
def getMeanCrossingRate(self, arr):
    return self.getZeroCrossingRate(np.array(arr) - np.mean(arr))
```

Comment: @Taha You can accept an answer that solves your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer